# Get Odd or Even Index Value from Variable in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

I need to get odd or even index value from a variable list:

For example:

```
- hosts: myhost
  vars:
    - var1: ["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5"]
    - odd_var: []
    - even_var: []
```

I need odd_var to be ["test1","test3","test5"] and even_var to be ["test2","test4"] and also concatenate each variable string of odd_var and even_var to be one string like:

odd_string: "test1,test3,test5"

even_string: "test2,test4"

What should i do to achieve this?

I have tried :

```
 - name: test
      set_fact:
        odd_list: "{{ odd_list | default([]) + [item] }}"
      loop: "{{ var1 }}"
      when: "{{ lookup('ansible.utils.index_of', var1, 'eq', item) is even }}
```

it works but i wonder if i can get more eficient way to do this

Comment: Jinja2 has [tests](https://jinja2docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/templates.html#builtin-tests) like `divisableby`, `odd`, `even` which are usable in ansible e.g. `my_var is odd`. You can extract a part of a string (to get only your index) with string index slicing, a `regex_replace` filter....., you can filter a list based on a test applied to each element with the `accept` or `reject` filters..... This is just to put you on track. Study the subject a bit more, then come back with an honest try to implement your requirement and an actual problem to fix on your implementation.

Comment: @Zeitounator i actually already have the answer to my problem, but i just want to see if there are more efficient way as solution to my problem

Comment: Well then say it  and show it. One main reason is to avoid someone to loose time coming up with the exact same solution your already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said "index value", I'm going to take you at your word and base it on position in the list, not the numbers contained in the strings.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    var1:
      - test1
      - test2
      - test3
      - test4
      - test5
    odd_var: "{{ var1[::2] | join(',') }}"
    even_var: "{{ var1[1::2] | join(',') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ odd_var }} / {{ even_var }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test1,test3,test5 / test2,test4"
}
```

Comment: This will work for this example, but if you have `test7` after `test5` instead of `test6`, this will not work as intended.

Comment: @user1098490 It *will* work as intended; I addressed that in the prefatory material. The question asks to base it on the index value, so the fact that `test7` contains an odd number is irrelevant.

Comment: My bad, I didn't read: _I need to get odd or even index value from a variable list._.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, checking the last character.

```
- var1: ["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5"]
- even: "{{ var1 | select('search','.*[02468]$') | join(',') }}"      
- odd: "{{ var1 | select('search','.*[13579]$') | join(',') }}"
```

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, though.